# how to send arraylist from one servlet to other servlet

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am trying to figure out why am i getting a null pointer exception.

when i try to execute addformservlet.
Help me in this issue i'm new to jsp servlets.

Please help me..

I am all stuck with part......

addform servlet:

```
      processRequest(HttpRequest req,HttpResponse res) 
      { 
      String []erlist=null;
      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
      response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
      try {
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Add dvd :</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body bgcolor='#E6599'>");
        if(erlist!=null)
        {
        out.println("<p>");
        out.println("<font color='red'>Correct the following errors:");
        out.println("<ul>");
        for(int i=0;i<erlist.length;i++)
           out.print("<li>"+erlist[i]+"</li>");

        out.println("</ul>");
        out.println("</font>");
        out.println("<a href='index.jsp'> back to index page</a>");
        out.println("</p>");
        }

        erlist=(String [])request.getSession().getAttribute("elist");// i get errlist from dvdaction.java

        out.println("<h2>Add DVD:  </h2>");
        out.println("<form action='dvdaction' method='post' >");//post page to dvdaction.java

        //some codes here....
        out.println("</form>");

        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");

       }

  //dvdaction.java:

        processRequest(HttpRequest req,HttpResponse res)

        {       
        String err[]=null;


       try {


        title=(String)request.getParameter("title");

        int i=0;

       if(title.trim().length()==0)
       {
        err[i]="Please add the title field";
        i++;
       }


       if(err.length==0)
       {

       //some codes here...
        }

        request.getSession().setAttribute("elist", err);// i set err Arraylist here...
        RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("adddvdformservlet");
        rd.forward(request, response);

    }
```

Comment: I don't see you create `err` anywhere and Java arrays are not dynamic. Basically, you should be getting `NullPointerException`s.

Comment: i crested err[] in dvdaction.java , the second processrequest()

Comment: before setting the  'err[i]="Please add the title field";' you should initialise with the number of errors or items you want

Comment: i added a filter page for adddvdform servlet and so null ptr ex. is thrown .. thanks i identified err reason in error stack .. thanks hamed i appreciate ur willingness to help in this case .. my code works fine..

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `err` array before assigning any value.
In `dvdaction.java`, initialize it as `String err[]=new String[5];` and then set it's value otherwise it will throw `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: Please post your recent code and did you check if error[] array has values if `title` is null.post your error stack trace also.

Comment: i added a filter page for adddvdform servlet and so null ptr ex. is thrown .. thanks i identified err reason in error stack .. thanks RRR i appreciate ur willingness to help in this case .. my code works fine.. –

Answer (score 0):

you should move this statement

```
erlist=(String [])request.getSession().getAttribute("elist");// i get errlist from dvdaction.java
```

before

```
 if(erlist!=null)
        {
        out.println("<p>");
        out.println("<font color='red'>Correct the following errors:");
        out.println("<ul>");
        for(int i=0;i<erlist.length;i++)
           out.print("<li>"+erlist[i]+"</li>");

        out.println("</ul>");
        out.println("</font>");
        out.println("<a href='index.jsp'> back to index page</a>");
        out.println("</p>");
        }
```

also before setting the  '`err[i]="Please add the title field";`' you should initialise with the number of errors or items you want .. let's assume 10

```
String err[]=new String[10];
```

I hope this could help!